# How to get unique record

Tags: sql, postgresql

how can we get unique record from data like

```
| letter_id | sender | to |
|-----------|--------|----|
| 20        | 13     | 12 |
| 20        | 13     | 11 |
| 20        | 13     | 10 |
| 20        | 11     | 13 |
```

i need to find record where `letter_id=20` and `sender=13` or `to=11`
or `sender=11` and `to=13` which mean if user has an `id=13 or 11`, 
the problem is users can be `sender` or `to`, i have tried using query like

`select * from pm where letter_id=20 and sender=13 or to=13` where `sender` and `to` come from my application session.

is there a way to avoid the result? or i have to change my table structur ?

Comment: ```select * from pm where letter_id=20 and ((sender=13 and to=11) OR (sender=11 and to=13))```?..

Comment: Your question is little bit unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for your problem is:

```
select * from pm
    where letter_id = @letter_Id and
          @user_session in (Sender,to)
```

Comment: I will try it latter, and come with the result

Comment: thanks buddy, solved with this, `Letters::where('letters_id',20)->whereRaw("$this->users in (sender,to)");`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select pm.*
from pm
where letter_id = 20 and
      (11, 13) in ( (sender, to), (to, sender) );
```

Or, this can be expressed as:

```
where letter_id = 20 and
      ( (sender = 11 and to = 13) or
        (sender = 13 and to = 11)
      )
```

Note:  `to` is a reserved word.  You need to escape the name or better yet change the name of the column in the table.

Comment: Lacking `letter_id=20`.

Comment: the problem is i can't get two parameter, in my application i have two paramater, 1st is `letter_id` and 2nd id `user session` which can be `sender` or `to`

Comment: Your comment, `1st is letter_id and 2nd id user session`, contradicts this part of your question, `where sender and to come from my application session.`.

Comment: I mean my application have 2 paramter letter id and user session which is user session can be `sender` or `to`